# Usage criteria for IAsyncResult.IsCompleted, iftAR.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne and AsyncCallback

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

I am learning the async concept of delegates and here I am confused on the difference between using the IAsyncResult.IsCompleted, iftAR.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne and AsyncCallback (in which you define new function with IAsyncResult as parameter).

I'm confused because suppose you use while loop to check for above 3 values, then in each of the 3 cases, you are checking in while loop whether the particular operation has completed executing. Then, what is the difference between the 3?

CASE 1 Code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {  
     Console.WriteLine("***** Async Delegate Invocation *****");  
      // Print out the ID of the executing thread.  
     Console.WriteLine("Main() invoked on thread {0}.",Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);  
      // Invoke Add() on a secondary thread.  
    BinaryOp b = new BinaryOp(Add); 
  IAsyncResult iftAR = b.BeginInvoke(10, 10, null, null);  
  // This message will keep printing until   
// the Add() method is finished.   
while(!iftAR.IsCompleted)  
 {   
  Console.WriteLine("Doing more work in Main()!"); 
    Thread.Sleep(1000);   
}  
 // Now we know the Add() method is complete. 
  int answer = b.EndInvoke(iftAR); 
     Console.WriteLine("10 + 10 is {0}.", answer);   
    Console.ReadLine();
     } 

     static int Add(int x, int y)    
     {     
      // Print out the ID of the executing thread.  
         Console.WriteLine("Add() invoked on thread {0}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);  
          // Pause to simulate a lengthy operation.   
        Thread.Sleep(5000);    
       return x + y; 
        }
```

CASE 2 code:If we replace the while loop with foll code:

```
while (!iftAR.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, true))
 {  
 Console.WriteLine("Doing more work in Main()!"); 
}
```

CASE 3 code:If we replace the while loop from CASE 1 with foll code and add the AddComplete method:

```
 while (!isDone)    
   {  
       Thread.Sleep(1000);  
       Console.WriteLine("Working...."); 
      }   

 static void AddComplete(IAsyncResult itfAR) 
   {     
  Console.WriteLine("AddComplete() invoked on thread {0}.",         Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);      
 Console.WriteLine("Your addition is complete");   
    isDone = true;  
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `IAsyncResult` is part of the APM pattern, which in itself has not much to do with delegates, but just uses a delegate for the callback. This pattern needs to be looked at as its own (quite complex) topic.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx)

That being said, the difference in summary is the following:

`IsComplete` is just a flag which lets you poll/check if the operation is complete or if it is still running.

The `WaitHandle` wraps an operating system primitive and allows to join a thread without using any CPU for the duration of the async operation, optionally with a timeout. When the timeout on `WaitOne` is set to 0, the operation is basically doing the same as `IsComplete` but at a much higher overhead cost.

The `callback` however allows to fire off an operation and "forget" about it; the callback will be called when the operation is complete, therefore allowing to continue at that point without actively polling or waiting. In the callback, the `IsComplete` will always be `true` and invoking `WaitOne.Join` would always immediately return.

*Note:* in your `AddComplete` callback, you should invoke the `EndInvoke`, not just set a synchronisation flag.

So if your use case is a `while` loop (a "spinning wait"), you should poll the `IsComplete` flag. The other two are used in other situations.

Comment: can you give a breif example of other situations. will be helpful as i am learning this concept

Comment: The examples are in my text: `WaitOne` for waiting for completion without wasting CPU resources (which spin-waiting typically does), `callback` for continuing work without waiting for completion in a separate thread (that is whenever synchronization of the call is not necessary).